# A horror film (scene) where a couple escape from a house with demon woman

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

A horror film (scene) where a couple escape from a house from a woman who changes into a demon (or possibly a vampire) in a well lit bathroom. They get into a car and think they have escaped, but it’s cut shot when they are chased. Possibly late 80s or 1990s.

Comment: This is possibly NIGHT OF THE DEMONS (1988) - it has the right timeframe, and involves people turning into demons in a house (including a woman in a bathroom).